# My ModelState.IsValid return false on .Net7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying register a new user basically. But ModelState.IsValid return false. I can't solve this problem. I am using Identity in this project.

Here is my UserRegisterController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MobimentiBackend.Core.Concrete;
using MobimentiBackend.Dto.UserDtos;

namespace MobimentiBackend.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserRegisterController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public UserRegisterController(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new User()
                {
                    Name = userRegisterDto.Name,
                    Surname = userRegisterDto.Surname,
                    Email = userRegisterDto.Email,
                };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userRegisterDto.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Ok(user);
                }
            }
            if (userRegisterDto.Password != userRegisterDto.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword", "Passwords are not matching.");
                return BadRequest(new { Message = "Failed registration", Errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) });
            }
            return BadRequest();

        }

    }
}
```

It's retun-rn BadRequest directly. I have user model. It is inherits IdentiyUser.
Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MobimentiBackend.Core.Concrete
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have Dto with name is UserRegisterDto
Here is the code:

```
namespace MobimentiBackend.Dto.UserDtos
{
    public class UserRegisterDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And Here is my request:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "surname": "user",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "password": "2~yEj7)w$Q",
  "confirmPassword": "2~yEj7)w$Q"
}
```

Finally I am adding Swagger screenshot result. You can check out my error:
[image]

ModelState.IsValid return false but it's not expected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689810/4172872

Comment: Sounds like it's having trouble binding the JSON you are sending.  Maybe include client side of your code.

Comment: Please share what is the request sent.

Comment: I am adding my JSON request now. And I am wondering is it about project type (Web API or MVC). My project is a Web API project

Comment: usually model binding will ignore case, but you might try matching the cases in the request.

Comment: you sure it's hitting your return BadRequest there and not throwing the error before you check the model?  (I say that because it looks like the request is fine... other things can cause bad request, like missing anti-forgery when that's turned on)

Answer (score 0):

Code seems fine to me, I hope issue is here, `if (result.Succeeded){return Ok(user);}`
what will happen if `CreateAsync` fails. Your method will `return BadRequest();`